# App hangs when run: cs_invalid_page error in logfile

Tags: code-signing

I'm trying to start Sony Sound Forge Pro. It's worked before, but then I tried to update to version 2 of the app, and I started getting this error when I start it. I downgraded back to version 1 and I still get the error.

The error is in the Console and it looks like this:

> 5/1/14 8:15:25.000 PM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10d2c1000): p=490[CoreServicesUIAg] final status 0x1000a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
>
> 5/1/14 8:15:25.000 PM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: process 490[CoreServicesUIAg]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x10d2c1000 from offset 0x11000 in file "/Applications/Sound Forge Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Sound Forge Pro" (cs_mtime:1365521695.0 == mtime:1365521695.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)

Is there any way to "reset" Apple's code signing and allow this application to run again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could ad-hoc sign the program yourself if you know it is a valid program, and not malware or similar.

From Terminal.app run a command like this:

sudo codesign -f -s - "/Applications/Sound Forge Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Sound Forge Pro"

"-f" means to force replace the existing, faulty, signature
"-s -" means to ad-hoc sign

The rest is the completely path and filename of the executable you want to sign.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Still having some trouble... this is what I get when I run that: http://dpaste.com/05Z7HVM/ And I still get the same console error.

Comment: Try adding --deep to the command, so it looks like this: sudo codesign -f --deep -s - "/Applications/Sound Forge Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Sound Forge Pro"

Comment: Same results with the `--deep` option

Comment: Have you checked that there is a Info.plist file for that framework within that folder? - If not, you need one.

Comment: I was able to get this to work with your command! `sudo codesign -f -s - "/Applications/Sound Forge Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Sound Forge Pro"`. I'm not sure what changed since last time, but I ran this command after deleting any trace off the app n `~/Library/`, and with a new user account, and after re-installing it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple workarounds to try if you can't find an answer:

#### 1) Time Machine

Use a Time Machine backup from before you upgraded as a system restore point.

#### 2) Temporary User Account

Create a temporary user account, see if the error still occurs when logged into the temporary account, and if not, return to the Finder and enter:

```
  shift-command-g
```

and in the field that appears type:

```
  ~/Library
```

and in the window that appears, take a look in these folders for preferences for the name of app in question, or the name of its developer:

```
 ~/Library/Preferences/
 ~/Library/Application\ Support/
 ~/Library/Caches/
```

and copy these files into a folder with a duplicate folder structure:

```
 /Users/Shared/mytempLibrary/Preferences/
 /Users/Shared/mytempLibrary/Application\ Support/name.of.folders
 /Users/Shared/mytempLibrary/Caches/name.of.folders
```

Log out and back into your main account and use the files you copied to /Users/Shared to replace the same files in your ~/Library by reitering some or all instructions in proper sequence to accomplish this.

Comment: The error still occurs in a new user account.