# Why can I open an app from Contents/MacOS/app but not by clicking the icon?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, permission

I have an application that is fully functional when opened from `Show Package Contents > /Contents/MacOS/app` however when I click the icon in the `Applications` folder the icon just keeps bouncing. Here is the console output when the Icon is clicked:

```
CoreServicesUIAgent[97331]: Error -60005 creating authorization
kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10a034000): p=97331[CoreServicesUIAg] final status 0x3000a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: process 97331[CoreServicesUIAg]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x10a034000 from offset 0x3000 in file "/Applications/App.app/Contents/MacOS/App" (cs_mtime:1429197754.0 == mtime:1429197754.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
```

Can someone tell me what this means and why this would happen?

Comment: What happens if you right click & select Open, from the .app rather than the contents?

Comment: The same error along with this:

`4/16/15 12:09:02.070 PM diagnosticd[62873]: error evaluating process info - pid: 958, punique: 300217`

`4/16/15 12:09:02.540 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.uiagent[958]) Binary is improperly signed.`

`4/16/15 12:09:35.159 PM mdworker[1053]: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67062.)"`

Comment: Sounds like gatekeeper and or a tampered app that is [normally paid](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/storyist/id921786088?mt=12) - is this app signed / from an App store / something you made or modified?

Comment: You can sign the app with adhoc profile, check this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130504

Comment: @SandeepChayapathi I literally just found this solution as you sent it in the comments. Thanks!